# Matplotlib subplots issue

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

The syntax is correct but not getting any plot:

```
sns.regplot(x='drat',y='carb',data=df,scatter=True)
```

Why I am not getting plot?

Instead this is displayed:

> 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x22766aacc18'

Comment: I suggest reading [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then editing your question. It is not clear, what you try to achieve and what your problem is.

Comment: In order to show a matplotlib plot, you need `pyplot.show()` or you need to use a backend that would automatically show images, like `%matplotlib inline`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using jupyter notebook, please write

```
%matplotlib inline
```

Answer (score 0):

You have create a plot

> 0x22766aacc18

is address of your plot. If you want to see your plot, you need code to show them, for example in pycharm:

```js
import matplotlib as plt
Your code that creat plot
#show plot
plt.show()
```